# Adding custom individual metadata to files to identify origin

Tags: file-management, metadata

I am starting a private course teaching a specialized technique to a group of 100+ members. I am aware that preventing videos from being leaked, copied, etc is nearly impossible (because at the most fundamental level you could just record the screen physically) but I'd like to prevent it as best as I can.

I've thought about adding a custom metadata field with each member's ID to the video for each member that it is given to, and that if it's leaked I can check the metadata and see who distributed it.

Does anyone else have any thoughts or experience with this kind of thing or know how I could add custom metadata fields to MP4 videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are products for hiding data inside video files, but there are also
others for scrubbing it out.

A simple method that would be hard to detect is to append some small data file
to the MP4 file.
This video format has an end marker, so any appended information is ignored when
it is played.

Under Windows, the batch command to use is:

```
copy video.mp4/b + datafile/b output.mp4
```

I wouldn't append the member's name to the video, since this can be found
just by opening the video file in a text-editor. Use some binary data
instead.